# Qual o valor sintático da oração?

Tags: sintaxe, pronomes

Estava lendo o jornal quando cheguei nesta parte: "Em torno de 5% da população recebeu ao menos uma dosa da vacina, o que nos coloca na 45ª posição no ranking mundial de doses aplicadas por habitante". Qual o valor sintático da oração «o que nos coloca na 45ª posição no ranking mundial de doses aplicadas por habitante»? Parece-me um caso de oração subordinada apositiva contra uma oração subordinada adjetiva. Eu suponho que seja a primeira (apositiva) porque não consigo substituir por "o qual" ou "a qual" e esse "o" que inicia a oração subordinada parece ser um aposto que pega toda a oração principal; entretanto estou inseguro quanto à afirmação.

Comment: Fica inseguro, não fiyo. Teu razonamento é excelente. :)

Answer (score 1):

Diria que não é apositiva, pois não funciona como aposto de algum termo anterior. Na verdade, não é nem uma oração subordinada também, uma vez que não possui papel nenhum numa oração superior.

É só outra oração que faz uma anáfora, no sentido pragmatico da palavra, com esse "o que" funcionando como um "isto"